# Upgrading react native version - app keep stopping

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, android-emulator

I upgraded to RN 0.60.5 and run "react-native run-android" and the project was successfully built. BUT, the emulator says that my app: "keep stopping". I also don't see any exceptions in node.js cli (if it is not getting closed - some times it is closed).

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 19
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0")
        classpath("io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
            maven {
                // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
                url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
            }
            maven {
                // Android JSC is installed from npm
                url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
            }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }

    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion 28
                }
            }
        }

        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                    details.useVersion "28.0.0"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
// apply plugin: "io.fabric"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js",
        enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.1"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
        compile project(':react-native-action-sheet')
        compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
        compile project(':react-native-android-location-enabler')
        compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
        compile project(':react-native-restart')
        compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        compile project(':react-native-calendar-events')
        compile project(':react-native-mail')
        compile project(':react-native-branch')
        compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
        compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
        compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
        compile project(':react-native-svg')
        compile project(':react-native-geocoder')
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.60.5"  // From node_modules
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
        implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
            exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
        }
        implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin"))
        compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
            transitive = false
        }
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0"
        implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation("com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0")
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
                force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
                force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
            }
        }

        if (enableHermes) {
            def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
            debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
            releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
            implementation jscFlavor
        }
    }

    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true


// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
    applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Anyone issued it? 
Any suggestions how to check for errors?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post your android/build.gradle and your android/app/build.gradle?
Also, have you used the command `react-native upgrade --legacy-true` ? It rebuilds the android folder. Be aware that it resets most of the basic configurations, like icons  and etc. They have some kind of wizard though.

Comment: @AndréPinto no, I haven't run ```react-native upgrade --legacy-true```, edited the post and uploaded the files. Thank you for answering so fast!

Comment: I saw you enabled multidex but didn't add the `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'` in the dependencies block in android/app/build.gradle.

Comment: @AndréPinto didn't helped

Comment: You could do a backup of your android/ios folder and make `react-native upgrade --legacy-true` ditching your old files and see if it works, i think that will provide information if it is some kind of upgrade problem. I also found [this](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) when i was upgrading the project I am working.

Comment: @AndréPinto running the cmmand with --legacy-true is not executing anything and with it says ```warn Specified version "0.60.5" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.60.5" semver range. No need to upgrade```